# Is it safe to cook pheasant medium?

Tags: meat, temperature, game

Am I right in thinking it's safe to cook pheasant breast medium so its a little pink?

If so why is this different from chicken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Canada's Safe internal cooking temperatures](http://healthycanadians.gc.ca/eating-nutrition/safety-salubrite/cook-temperatures-cuisson-eng.php) article, game birds including pheasant should be cooked to an internal temperature as follows:

- Whole 82°C (180°F)
- Breasts and roasts    74°C (165°F)
- Thighs, wings 74°C (165°F)
- Stuffing (cooked alone or in bird)    74°C (165°F)

These temperatures will be decidedly not pink (except possibly around the bones), but will maximize the safety of eating game.